# Stuck with unwanted advertisements in-game

Tags: ios, games

Whilst playing Angry Birds with my grandson, an ad for another game kept appearing. Despite trying to close this ad several times, I now find myself stuck with this game app on screen inviting me to download.

All other 'buttons', features, refresh, etc are inactive. How do I escape from this app and return to the wanted game?

Answer (score 1):

You can [force the app to close](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5137) and then reopen it:

```
 1. Double-click the Home button.
 2. Swipe left or right until you have located the app you wish to close.
 3. Swipe the app's preview up to close it.
```

Now reopen the app from the Home screen and you should be set.

Pro Tip: Sometimes tapping excessively with an app can cause it to slow down, freeze or lock up like you describe.

Answer (score 0):

If other force-quit solutions don't do anything, try the old-school way:

1. Press and hold the lock/sleep button until "slide to power off" appears.
2. Press and hold the home button until the application quits and returns to the home screen.

If that doesn't work, then you're going to have to force-shutdown the iOS device:

1. Press and hold both the lock/sleep button and the home button until your iOS device turns off.
2. Release the buttons, and the Apple logo will appear.